# Sending data from arduino to python through serial

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-ide

I write a code to read data from Arduino and check digital input high or log to a python program but I am facing difficulties. Program is working properly for sending and receiving data through serial but the problem is occurring on the digital read pin. It is not reading the pin if high and also sending wrong high low information. My code is given below:

for Arduino:

```
int inPin30 = 30;
int inPin31 = 31;
int inPin32 = 32;
int inPin33 = 33;
int inPin34 = 34;
int inPin35 = 35;
int inPin36 = 36;
int inPin37 = 37;
int inPin38 = 38;


int outPin2 = 2;
int outPin3 = 3;
int outPin4 = 4;
int outPin5 = 5;
int outPin6 = 6;
int outPin7 = 7;
int outPin8 = 8;
int outPin9 = 9;
int outPin10 = 10;

int in0 = 0;
int in1 = 0;
int in2 = 0;
int in3 = 0;
int in4 = 0;
int in5 = 0;
int in6 = 0;
int in7 = 0;
int in8 = 0;
String str = "";


String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = 0; // whether the string is complete
boolean stringComplete1 = 0;
void setup() {
    // input pin 
     pinMode(inPin30, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin31, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin32, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin33, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin34, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin35, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin36, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin37, INPUT);
     pinMode(inPin38, INPUT);
    // output pin 
     pinMode(outPin2, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin3, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin4, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin5, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin6, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin7, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin8, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin9, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(outPin10,OUTPUT);

  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
   //call the function
  // print the string when a newline arrives:

  serialEvent();
  if (stringComplete1==1) {

    // pin 2 high low
    if (inputString[0]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin2, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[0]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin2, LOW);

    }

    // pin 3
       if (inputString[1]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin3, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[1]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin3, LOW);

    }
    // pin 4
        if (inputString[2]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin4, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[2]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin4, LOW);

    }
    // pin 5
        if (inputString[3]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin5, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[3]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin5, LOW);

    }
    // pin 6
        if (inputString[4]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin6, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[4]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin6, LOW);

    }
    // pin 7

        if (inputString[5]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin7, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[5]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin7, LOW);

    }
    // pin 8

        if (inputString[6]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin8, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[6]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin8, LOW);

    }
    // pin 9

        if (inputString[7]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin9, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[7]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin9, LOW);

    }
    // pin 10
        if (inputString[8]=='1')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin10, HIGH);

    }

     if (inputString[8]=='0')
    {
    digitalWrite(outPin10, LOW);

    }






    Serial.print(inputString);
    delay(1000);
    // clear the string:
    inputString = "";

  }


   if (stringComplete==0) {
        in0= digitalRead(inPin30);
    in1= digitalRead(inPin31);
    in2= digitalRead(inPin32);
    in3= digitalRead(inPin33);
    in4= digitalRead(inPin34);
    in5= digitalRead(inPin35);
    in6= digitalRead(inPin36);
    in7= digitalRead(inPin37);
    in8= digitalRead(inPin38);


     String str=String(in0)+String(in1)+String(in2)+String(in3)+String(in4)+String(in5)+String(in6)+String(in7)+String(in8)+'\n';
     Serial.print(str);
       //if (str[9] == '\n') {
      stringComplete = 1;
    //}
     delay(1000);

    }
}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
 hardware serial RX.  This routine is run between each
 time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
 response.  Multiple bytes of data may be available.
 */
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete1 = 1;
      stringComplete = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

python code:

```
import serial, time
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=.1)
arduino.setDTR(level=False)
time.sleep(0.5)
arduino.flushInput()
arduino.setDTR()
time.sleep(0.5)
x =0
if x== 0:
    data = arduino.readline()
    print data
    time.sleep(3)
    x= 1
while True:
    arduino.write("111111111\n")
    data = arduino.readline()
    print data
    time.sleep(3)
    data1 = arduino.readline()
    print data1
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Is it normal to have in1 several time `String(in1)+String(in1)+String(in1)+String(in1)+String(in1)+String(in1)+String(in1)+String(in1)` ? not linked you should use define for `inPinXX` and `outPinXX`, and I think using a loop can save lot of code

Comment: @Ôrel this is not the problem I am facing :( . I edited code but still not working